# Excel Time Formatting

Tags: excel, time, format

So, I have an app, which automatically creates Excel tables. One of the column in those tables is something like a duration for a task. The format of the data looks like this: "1h12min" or "5min".
Now I want to be able to sum up all those numbers and have a total duration of all tasks.
I have tried using custom cell formatting, but I wasn't able to solve the problem that way, mostly because all time formats require a certain input method (like 00:00) and using '#' for the minutes resulted in them stacking up to 100 instead of 60.
I was gonna try an approach where I create one or more extra columns that convert those numbers into time format with the help of stuff like IF and CONTAINS functions, but my attempts are not working out.
Does anyone know of a good way to solve this problem?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So if you things like "1h12min" then you need to get the number of hours, convert to minutes, sum the minutes and do the same for all time entries. Did that for data I have to use and it’s a very long formula. Works well though.

Answer (score 0):

So this was my example:

So, cell DK8 contained "9 mins 18 secs".

The result "9.30"

And the function:

```
IFERROR(IF(ISERR(FIND("sec",DK8,1)),LEFT(DK8,FIND(" ",DK8,1)-1),LEFT(DK8,FIND(" ",DK8,1)-1)+(MID(DK8,FIND(" ",DK8,FIND(" ",DK8,1)+1)+1,FIND(" ",DK8,FIND(" ",DK8,4)+1)-FIND(" ",DK8,FIND(" ",DK8,1)+1)))/60),"")
```

You will need to edit to suit for hours etc